# AngularJS - Remove ng-repeat item if contains string(s)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, replace, filtering, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've been cleaning up an external JSON URL feed that I am using, and I have successfully removed unnecessary special characters via a filter as so:

```
angularJS.filter('removeChar', function(){
    return function(text) {
        text = text.replace(/\[[^\]]+\]/g, ''); // Characters inside Brackets
        return text.replace(/\;.*/, ''); // Characters after Colon
    };
});

<span ng-bind-html-unsafe="item | removeChar">{{item}}</span>
```

However, what I am trying to achieve now - is to remove an ng-repeat item if it contains a specific string via a filter I can use.

For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | removeItem">{{item['flowers']}}</div>
```

If the item contains the word 'Red' or 'Green'

```
<div>Blue Roses</div>
<div>Red Roses</div>
<div>Orand and Green Roses</div>
<div>Yellow Roses</div>
<div>Red and Green Roses</div>
```

Only this will display from the ng-repeat with the filter:

```
<div>Blue Roses</div>
<div>Yellow Roses</div>
```

Help with an example would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks!
Roc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a `filter` along with the ! predicate that negates the search string:

```
div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:'!Red' | filter: '!Green'">{{item['flowers']}}</div>
```

So `filter:'!Red'` removes anything that does have the string "Red" in it. Those results are passéd to `filter: '!Green'` which removes any results that have the string "Green" in them.

Here's the relevant docs:  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter

**Performance Update**

I was curious about the cost of filtering so I did this jsperf:  http://jsperf.com/angular-ng-repeat-test1/2

I created 1,000 strings (`items`) and then did 4 tests with the following results on my system:

**1)** Display all 1000 using DI        **281,599 ops/sec**

```
  {{items}}
```

**2)** Display all 1000 using `ng-repeat` (no-filter):   **209,946 ops/sec**  16% slower

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in items"> {{item}}</div>
```

**3)** `ng-repeat` with one filter **165,280 ops/sec** 34% slower

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:filterString1"> {{item}}</div>
```

**4)** `ng-repeat` with two filters **165,553, ops/sec** 38% slower

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:filterString1 | filter:filterString2"> {{item}}</div>
```

This is certainly not a scientific test- I didn't do any controls and it's possible for things like caching to have influenced the results.  But I think the relative performance is interesting.

Comment: Thanks Dave!
Exactly what I was looking for. Two questions:
1) Do you see any performance impact if the filtered content is less than 300 objects? Most likely 100 or less?
2) How difficult would it be to place all of the predicates into one .filter function?
Thank you again Dave!

Comment: While certainly more items does have a performance impact. I think you should be fine with 300. I've seen numbers float around about 2,000 being where issues creep in. But that's anecdotal. If you really want solid numbers you could always toss the code into jsperf.com and compare with vs without filtering.  2) It's easy do multiple `or` tests in one filter. But you need to `and` them. So I'd write my own. They're easy: docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09 And looks like Daniel has posted an approach to that.

Answer (score 7):

You can use any function available in the current scope as the argument of `filter`. So you could write something like this, for example.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="FooCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:myFilter">
            {{item}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function FooCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = ["foo bar", "baz tux", "hoge hoge"];

    $scope.myFilter = function(text) {
        var wordsToFilter = ["foo", "hoge"];
        for (var i = 0; i < wordsToFilter.length; i++) {
            if (text.indexOf(wordsToFilter[i]) !== -1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    };
}
```

Here is a working Fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/2tpb3/